# Convert or remove old svn branches when migrating to mercurial

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial, migration, branch

We are about to migrate from subversion to mercurial. We have settled for a mercurial workflow with a single repository and two branches (`default` and `stable`).

The subversion repository we want to migrate has lots of old feature branches that we do not need anymore.

Should we convert those branches and close them or remove them before the final conversion? Why should we do one or the other?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any way: both are (more or less) usable.

I'll prefer (if you haven't problem with Subversion binding) to use [Convert Extension with --filemap option](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--filemap) (convert repo-root point), and `exclude path/to/not-needed-branch` as fastest and easiest way

Comment: could you elaborate on the *more or less*? :)

Comment: @netrunner - yes. "Both solution will hide old history, but in case of *closing* converted branches in Mercurial repo you still have **full** history, removed /with history-rewriting or skipped in conversion/ branches remove part of development history"

Comment: thanks for elaborating! History-rewriting is indeed one of the arguments against removing those branches... Can you think of any other argument against, or in favor of doing so?

Comment: @netrunner - I prefer to have all history, but for some developers for already merged branches **branch history** has zero value - they have final mergeset with all changes. I have not definitive answer, which way is better and more correct